# SRP and DRY confusion

Tags: oop, dry, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am new to developing clean codes and trying to discipline myself with principles. My application has 3 user entities and each user entities have different data sources. When it comes to authentication logic, all 3 entities will use the same logic, except from data source. What I am doing now is, I separated the logic into 3 different classes for each entities (for the sake for different data sources) and feels like I am violating the DRY principle.

I used to do like this (I'll just use pseudo code):

`class Auth`
`loginFunction(dto,loginType){`
`connect to datasource for auth(datasource = loginType=A?datasourceA:loginTypeB?datasourceB:datasourceC)`
`}`

What I am doing now is this:

`class AuthA`
`loginFunction(dto){`
`}`
`class AuthB`
`loginFunction(dto){`
`}`
`class AuthC`
`loginFunction(dto){`
`}`

For the first approach, I feels like I am violating SRP because, the class is responsible for handling authentication for all the entities. I can argue that it's responsibility is just to handle authentication, regardless of the number of entities. But then again, I feel like each entity's authentication should be handled by their own respective classes. And hence, the second approach. But the second approach have same logic repeated across all classes, with the only difference of datasource.

I feel like both approaches aren't right. Is there any way to handle this as eloquently as possible? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm undestanding correctly but I think you are looking for inheritance where you have a base class like `BaseAuth` which will be extended for each specific "Auth" class and each specific class will implement its own `datasource`.

And also, It's not a good idea connect to the datasource into `login` method. Your `Auth` class is doing two things: Connect to DataSource and Login the user.

So you can have something like this example (I've used Java):

```java
abstract class BaseAuth {
  protected DataSource dataSource;
  
  public BaseAuth(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }
  
  public void login(LoginDTO dto) {
    // this.datasource.connect().login() or whatever
    // for testing I've added this line:
    System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + this.dataSource.toString());
  }
}
```

And each specific class will implement its own `datasource` and will be accessible via `login` method.

Something like this:

```java
class AuthA extends BaseAuth {
  public AuthA() {
    super(new DataSourceA());
  }
}
```

Now `AuthA` creates its own `DataSourceA`. The same way for `B` and `C`. So the class `AuthX` provide the datasource while the base class provide the login logic.

And `DataSource` from `BaseAuth` can be another abstraction (interface or abstract class):

```java
interface DataSource { }
```

Where each `DataSourceX` implements `DataSource`.

I've created this `DataSource` example overriding `toString()` to test the example:

```java
class DataSourceA implements DataSource {

  public DataSourceA() {
    // here the specific implementation
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "DataSource A";
  }
}
```

So now:

1. `BaseAuth` class allows you to call `.login()` method regardless it is called from `AuthA`, `AuthB` or `AuthC`. Login is not repeated and this class only have the responsability to do the login.
2. When each "auth" class is created, it also creates its own `DataSource`. So each auth has only the responsability to create its own datasource.
3. `.login()` will call the specific `DataSource` for the specific class.

Then, if you do (removing the DTO object from the method to read better):

```java
BaseAuth auth = new AuthA();
auth.login();
auth = new AuthB();
auth.login();
auth = new AuthC();
auth.login();
```

The result will be:

```bash
DATASOURCE = DataSource A
DATASOURCE = DataSource B
DATASOURCE = DataSource C
```

Note how you don't have to repeat code. You have only one `login` method which will execute the according `DataSource`.

By the way and as append I will remember you another principle "[Duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction)". If you are not completly sure the abbstraction is ok... don't try that.